# button activated on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, button

i have to click twice to activate the button, here is my HTML code

```
<button id="bt" on="false" onclick="onOf()">
      display
</button>

 <div id="bookmark" style="visibility: hidden">
```

and the js code:

```
function onOf() {
 if (document.getElementById("bt").on == "false") {
  document.getElementById("bt").on = "true";
  document.getElementById("bt").innerHTML = "hide";
  document.getElementById("bookmark").style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
  document.getElementById("bt").on = "false";
  document.getElementById("bt").innerHTML = "display";
  document.getElementById("bookmark").style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
}
```

the button should hide and display a div on every click, acutally it works but the first click has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Because the on property of the button element is an invalid attribute, you must click the button twice to activate it. To save unique information about the element, use the **data-*** property instead.

Here is the following corrected code:

```js
function onOf() {
  var bt = document.getElementById("bt");
  var bookmark = document.getElementById("bookmark");

  if (bt.getAttribute("data-on") === "false") {
    bt.setAttribute("data-on", "true");
    bt.innerHTML = "hide";
    bookmark.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    bt.setAttribute("data-on", "false");
    bt.innerHTML = "display";
    bookmark.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="bt" data-on="false" onclick="onOf()">
  display
</button>

<div id="bookmark" style="display: none;">
  <!-- code -->
</div>
```